# Recycler view doesn't show data in Portrait mode in Android nougat

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-7.0-nougat

I am developing an app with `RecyclerView` showing a set of data. But the `RecyclerView` is not showing data (While the device is is PORTRAIT mode) in NOUGAT but it's working fine in Marshmallow (both in LANDSCAPE AND PORTRAIT). I checked this [link][1] and updated my code as per this but still I am facing this issue. I don't know where I am wrong.

**Here is my xml code:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**Activity code:**

```
   RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
   recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); // added as per the link
   recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
   recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

[GitHub link](https://github.com/amardeshbd/android-recycler-view-wrap-content)

This code shows data in **LANDSCAPE MODE in NOUGAT** but not in **PORTRAIT** MODE.Works in both mode in **MARSHMALLOW**.
Any help would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you get any logcat warning in nought device?

Comment: No , I am not getting any @DivyeshPatel

Comment: make NestedScrollview height match_parent and remove fillviewport.

Comment: Not working @DivyeshPatel

Answer (score 0):

make NestedScrollview height match_parent and use

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
```

instead of your line of code. why are you using notifyDataSetChanged() after just setting up the adapter?

Comment: Getting same issue @Payam Kokabi

Comment: in your xml if you dont have another view use RecyclerView alone instead of implementing it in NestedScrollView and LinearLayout @Anusha

Comment: I tried even that. Still the same problem. @Payam Kokabi